# Multiple Reclassifications by a variable

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, parameters, reclassify

I am using Model Builder to reclassify a DEM raster (the input raster is a parameter and may vary in range of elevations). (The model then goes on to extract the highest point in each patch above a given elevation.) I can classify above and below a fixed height, but what I would like to do is make multiple passes, incrementing the classification cutoff by, say, 10 each pass (or pass the increment as a parameter). How can I change the Old Values line to accept the changing cutoff? I see there is a Load and Save function, but I am unclear how I would write a table within Model Builder. Ideally the model would have the start elevation, the interval, and the final elevation as input parameters. I can do this in Python, but would like to have it in Model Builder format.

Comment: I'm not sure you can directly modify the the 'old values' parameter of the reclassify tool in model builder. You could maybe make a template remap table, then in model builder use a for loop to iteratively copy that template, recalculate values for the 'from value' and 'to value' fields', and then use those new tables as inputs for 'reclassify by table'

Comment: If your reclassification is binary (i.e. a single threshold) however, maybe it would be easier to simply use the Con() tool